# How to set defaultcontentype in ServiceStack version 4

Tags: servicestack

According to the documentation, in the new version of ServiceStack, default content type is supposed to be set like (I am guessing the string "application/json", since this is not documented) in my AppHost class:

```
public override void Configure(Container container) {
  SetConfig(new HostConfig { DefaultContentType = "application/json" });
}
```

This does not work for me. If I return a result like:

```
return new HttpResult(new MyClass(2, new float[2]{0.0f, 0.4f}), "application/json");
```

it properly returns json-formattet output, but if I do

```
return new HttpResult(new MyClass(2, new float[2]{0.0f, 0.4f}));
```

It does not. I would expect it to output json.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am guessing the string "application/json", since this is not documented

You can use the string `application/json` or you can use the constant `MimeTypes.Json`. But JSON is the default content type.

However you are not getting JSON back for your response, where you don't explicitly set the content type header, because ServiceStack will honour the browser's `Accept` request header. So when you make a request from your browser, it asks for `text/html` by default. Which ServiceStack will response with.

You have some options, you can:

1. Explicitly set the return type in the method, as you did in your example code. Or use a the `AddHeader` attribute:

   ```cs
   [AddHeader(ContentType=MimeTypes.Json)]
   public MyResponse Get(MyRequest request)
   {
      ...
   ```
2. Explicitly make requests with the content type set:

   - Set Accept header *i.e.* `Accept: application/json`
   - Append `.json` to the route *i.e.* `/SomeAction.json`
   - Add a `format` property to the query string *i.e.* `/SomeAction?format=json`
3. You can disable ServiceStack's HTML feature, and set the default return type to JSON:

   ```cs
   public override void Configure(Funq.Container container)
   {
       SetConfig(new HostConfig { 
           DefaultContentType = MimeTypes.Json,
           EnableFeatures = Feature.All.Remove(Feature.Html)
       });
   }
   ```

   There is currently a bug in v4 that produces a "Forbidden" error at present for this option. But I notified the team and it's been sorted in [this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/fd7b74a84fd3a5ca08efc808e62cb524022b9c8c). So this option should work in the next release (4.0.16).